# Deciding between cursive and print handwriting

Tags: exams, coursework, formatting

I was taught cursive in elementary school but was discouraged from using cursive by an English teacher in in a non English speaking country. At least I took his/her comment that “not many people use cursive these days” as a sign not to use cursive. Later I practiced and adopted a “connected print” style, because I feared there might me legibility issues for standardized tests. In college, naturally I continued the use of connected print. However, this is slow and laborious, so if you use this in handwritten exams, your mind is distracted from thinking about the question.

How can I choose which style to use? Does it depend on the professor? Is there any evidence that professors prefer either style?

Comment: Have you considered typing your work?

Comment: Most in-class exams are in written form though.

Comment: *At least I took his/her comment that "not many people use cursive these days" as a sign not to use cursive.* – Of course a lot depends on the tone here, but have you ever considered that you completely misinterpreted a mere expression of surprise or even compliment here? Would you think analogously about “Not many people can multiply four-digit numbers in their head nowadays”?

Comment: @guest Bring a mechanical typewriter ;) - Noise might be a problem though...

Answer (score 21):

Most professors prefer handwriting that is legible.

I have seen some (asian weirdly, all other nationalities tend to a larger style and there are 90+ nationalities in the establishment) students with handwriting **so** small it is difficult to read but perfectly formed though.

Some write cursive others like small caps but all are fine when neat and legible.

The issue is always the “spider scrawl” that is not legible and so poor that even the author can’t read it later.

Answer (score 8):

Professors are people, and people have various preferences. Ask your professor if it’s preferred to use hand writing for assignments and you will get your answer.

Comment: While there may be a very small minority of professors who has a preference here, I am quite confident that most professors do not care at all as long as it’s readable and will tell you exactly this. Moreover you risk leaving the impression of somebody who cannot make their own decisions and wastes their time. I therefore would advise asking professors. (Mind that am not accusing the asker of not being able to make their own decisions. Asking the question here is a way to find out *how* to make a decision.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I agree completely, assuming you mean _I therefore would advise **NOT** asking professors._

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Seriously? Any professor that finds a straightforward question _asking for their preferences_ a waste of time deserves to have their time wasted.  Just ask.

Comment: @Kimball: Indeed.

Comment: @JeffE: Everything can be overdone. Just imagine every student would ask for one such detail, let alone every detail on that level (choice of paper, choice of ink color, variant of English, …). Moreover, here the question is mostly orthogonal to what is actually important for most (readability and efficiency). If anything, you would have to present the professor two samples of handwriting.

Answer (score 3):

**There is a cultural component to this as well, so this may vary between countries.**

In France for instance children are taught to write in cursive. When I was a kid we had calligraphy classes, now it is just the cursive.

So when someone in France thinks "handwritten document", they expect cursive.

Of course, if the document comes written the US way (print handwriting) it is fine. If it comes in ALL CAPS then it is weird.

**The most important part is for it to be readable** (except if you are an archeologist, or a medical doctor - which seems to be a world wide tendency. A scary one if you ask me because I cannot think of another job where WIRIWIEAICKM (What I Read Is What I Eat And It Can Kill Me - but I digress)

Answer (score 1):

While there may be some odd professor who has an actual preference for a handwriting style per se, the more relevant factors are whether your writing is easily readable and whether it does not distract you too much.

I therefore suggest to do the following:

1. Produce samples for each of your two handwriting styles. Impose a time limit. Also, make it a mental challenge, for instance try to reproduce a piece of information from the depths of your memory or translate a text into another language. Make the challenges for each sample as similar as possible, but not identical to avoid a bias towards whatever you do second, e.g., do not recite the same poem twice, but use the odd verses for one sample and the even ones for the other. Ideally let somebody else surprise you with the challenge.
2. Show the samples to a friend who is not intimately familiar with your handwriting and let them judge their readability. If they consider either sample considerably more readable, choose this.
3. Should both samples score equally in the previous step, go by the handwriting style which you felt to be least distracting. If there is a significant difference in the number of mistakes you made for one sample, take this into account.

Whatever the outcome, stick to this style from now on to train and optimise it.